# Cannot read property '0' of undefined when I change back tabs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, state, rendering

I am working on a personal project and I am trying to fetch data from an API that I have running on my server. Before the first implementation of the code, everything works fine, even after I write my code and save it the first time it works alright. *But* after I do this and switch my navigation tabs back and forth once, everything breaks and I get "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

[image]

I would like to fetch all my data in one place and then just get what I need from it willingly.

This is the fetching function:

```
//i have my state here
const [rezultateEz, setRezultateEz] = useState()

//code for fetching the data
const ezFetcher = async () => {
        const intrebare = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/ezquestions')
        const res = await intrebare.json();
        setRezultateEz(res)
    }

//i then call my function inside a useEffect
useEffect(() => {
        ezFetcher();
    }, [])


//and so i can just test it i try to run it inside this JSX here
 <div className={style.questionHolder}>
                {rezultateEz[0].question}
 </div>
```

The res property has a `question, all_answers array and correct_answer` inside it, which I want to access more easily with this function but I can't really do it because of the error presented earlier. How can I do that?

I tried using try catch or saving different pieces of state individually but nothing worked.

I will kindly accept any piece of advice or information given, and thank you for the time you spent reading my question

Comment: would `{rezultateEz[0]?.question}` not do the job already?

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz I just tried it but no, it has the same behaviour, thanks for the input though

Comment: add a default value for the rezultateEz. ```const [rezultateEz, setRezultateEz] = useState([])```

Comment: @SimaAmini I am so freaking dumb!!!!! Thank you for pointing it out, and thanks for the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to set

```
const [rezultateEz, setRezultateEz] = useState([])
```